# My SQL Statement doesn't work with "DEFAULT VALUES" receiving a claus error

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm trying to execute the following code but I am receiving a claus error:

```
Sql.Add('SELECT * ');

Sql.Add(' INTO [' + myTableName + ']');

Sql.Add(' FROM ' + myOtherTName);

Sql.Add(' VALUES (DEFAULT) ');

ExecSql;
```

The code does well execute if I remove the "VALUES (DEFAULT)" statement.

I'm using Delphi 10.

Comment: Did you try this directly in mysql? No you didn't. Otherwise you would have realised that Delphi is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @CraigYoung I'm pretty sure this isn't MySQL... OP just chose a confusing set of word "My SQL..." But indeed, this is in no way related to Delphi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql#syntax), `DEFAULT` (and `DEFAULT VALUES`) is part of the `INSERT` syntax, not part of `SELECT`.  It is not part of the table-constructor syntax for `VALUES` when used in a `FROM` clause.